# ¿Cómo definir una serie de tiempo?

Tags: r

Tengo un problema con unas series de tiempo en **R**, con la función `ts()`. ¿Cómo se deberían poner los parámetros de tiempo cuando la serie es diaria? ¿Cómo se configura el `start` y el `end`?

Este es el código que he usado:

```
producto1 <- ts(citas2$CANCELADA, start=c(2013,7), end=c(2013,10), 
frequency = 365)#,7), end=c(2013,10) , frequency = 12)#, end=c(2013,10,31), frequency=365)
producto1 plot(producto1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a crear una serie diaria y buscas que está comience un determinado día, el truco es calcular el día del año del mismo. Supongamos que queremos que nuestra serie de tiempo comience en `2017-07-01`, una forma de resolverlo mediante R base es:

```
day = as.numeric(strftime('2017-07-01', format = "%j"))
producto1 <- ts(citas2$CANCELADA, start = c(2017, day), frequency = 365)
```

Sino, es algo más cómodo usando el paquete `lubridate`:

```
library(lubridate)
producto1  <- ts(citas2$CANCELADA, start = c(2017,yday('2017-07-01')), frequency = 365)
```